# Using Google Maps with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I am trying to use google maps in my application.I have added google services maps and location services to the components of my application I was following tutorials and looking at the documentation about how it is meant to be implemented and it used to require google play services which has since been separated into multiple smaller components. Anyways when ever i run the application a button appears saying get google play service on my app and when I click it an error appears.
Thanks for any help.

Unhandled Exception:

```
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details? id=com.google.android.gms&pcampaignid=gcore_8115000--- flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
```

Here is my code:

```
//main.xaml
    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
//Main Activity
       public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
        {

         private GoogleMap mMap;
                protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
                {
                        base.OnCreate(bundle);
                        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                        SetUpMap();
                }
            private void SetUpMap()
            {
                if (mMap == null)
               {
                        FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
                }

            }
            public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
            {
                mMap = googleMap;
            }
    }
```

Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="app1.app1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
         <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
         <application android:label="app1" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
        <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/Google_Maps_Key" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       </application>

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
       <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
       <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       <!-- Permission to receive remote notifications from Google Play Services -->
      </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi everyone so I found the solution to my issue basically the xamarin emulator doesn't come with google play services by default so unfortunately I overlooked installing them on the emulator. So even though I added it to the components and also the sdk forgot that step.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you did wrong, but see this link, it helped me a lot to implement google maps. ;)

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Q0olRPsus][1]

Comment: That's exactly the tutorial I was following XD, Just a quick question when he installed google play services, did you use google play services maps instead?